# Как запускать javascript каждый раз с прелоадером?

Tags: javascript, opencart

Есть модуль для opencart "всплывающая корзина"

Весь код работает, но не всегда отображает нужное с первого раза.
Чтобы было понятней:

- добавляем товар в корзину
- открывается корзина, а она пуста
- заходим в корзину ещё раз и товар уже отображается как добавленный.

Нужно, чтобы корзина обновлялась с первого раза, и чтобы стили не бегали пока загружается код, покупателю показывался прелоадер (что мол идёт обработка запроса)

Вот код этого модуля:

```
(function($){

    var modPopupCart = {};

    // URI для загрузки содержимого корзины
    var popupCartUri = 'index.php?route=module/popupcart/load';
    // URI страницы оформления заказ
    var cartCheckoutUri = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';

    // div
    var popupCartContainer = '#popupcart';
    var popupCartTitle = 'div.title';
    var popupCartContent = '#popupcart .popupcart_content';

    /*
    * Инициализация контейнера
    */
    modPopupCart.init = function(config){
        var defConf = {};
        var $this = this;

        defConf = {
            draggable : "1",
        };

        config = $.extend({},defConf,config);

        // Настройка эффекта draggable
        if( parseInt(config.draggable) == 1 ){
            $(popupCartContainer).draggable({ handle: popupCartTitle });
        }

        $(popupCartContainer).disableSelection();
        $(popupCartContainer).resizable({
            maxHeight: 800,
            maxWidth: 800,
            minHeight: 530,
            minWidth: 600,
            alsoResize: popupCartContent
        });
        $(popupCartContent).resizable();

        // Останавливаем дальншейшее всплытие события "click" при клике на область окна
        $(popupCartContainer).click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        // по клику на область вне окна корзины закрываем окно
        $('body').click(function(){
            $this.close();
        });

        $('body').keydown(function(event){
            if(event.which == 27) { // ESC 
                $this.close();
            }
        });     
    };

    /*
    * Открытие окна корзины
    */
    modPopupCart.open = function(){
        $(popupCartContent).load(popupCartUri,{},function(){
            $(popupCartContainer).css('top', ($(window).height()/2-$(popupCartContainer).height()/2)+ $(window).scrollTop());
            $(popupCartContainer).css('left', $(window).width()/2-$(popupCartContainer).width()/2);
            $(popupCartContainer).css("position","absolute");
            $(popupCartContainer).css("z-index","9999");
            $("#pop_back").last().addClass("pop_back");
            $(popupCartContainer).show();   
        });

        return false;
    };

    /*
    * Закрытие окна корзины
    */
    modPopupCart.close = function(){
        $(popupCartContainer).hide();
        $(popupCartContent).empty();
        $("#pop_back").removeClass("pop_back");
        return false;
    };

    /*
    * Удаление товарной позиции
    */
    modPopupCart.removeProduct = function(productId){
        if(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
            location = cartCheckoutUri + '&remove=' + productId;
        } else {
            $(popupCartContent).load(popupCartUri + '&remove=' + productId);
            $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove='  + productId + ' #cart > *');
        }
    }

    /*
    * Удаление ваучера
    */
    modPopupCart.removeVoucher = function(voucherId){
        if(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
            location = cartCheckoutUri + '&remove=' + voucherId;
        } else {
            $(popupCartContent).load(popupCartUri+'&remove=' + voucherId);
            $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove='  + voucherId + ' #cart > *');
        }
    }

    window.modPopupCart = modPopupCart;
})($);
```

Comment: http://freelansim.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, что в функции `modPopupCart.open` в метод `load` передается URL, но не передается данные объекта `{}`, то есть на сервер ничего не уходит, и ответ сервер не присылает. Ну и как еще вариант надо смотреть , что возвращается в методе контроллера `module/popupcart/load`. В общем нужно отлаживать код в браузере.